# X11 style "Copy & Paste" on windows 7, but not True X-Mouse

Tags: windows-7

I search for X11 style middle mouse button.
There is a [TXMouse](http://fy.chalmers.se/~appro/nt/TXMouse/) that seems to just overwrite the middle click, so for example
it blocks opening links in browser with middle click.
Is there a software that would not interfere with normal use and still use CTRL to paste it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use this for my Evoluent mouse. It has "per application" settings:

http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/XMouseButtonControl.htm

Answer (score 0):

I was a fervent user of TXMouse before, but for some reasons I didn't kept it when getting a Win7 work laptop... I can't recall if wasn't working or what, but for the middlemouse issue you describe my fix was to blacklist the browser and use an add-on that implements the select-paste functionality.

I just tried X-Mouse Button Control, and while it does provide the middle-click paste functionality I can't seem to find a way to get select-copy behaviour... Looks like the copy function they mention has to be bound to a mouse button (4th or 5th?).

So the one I've used since then was AutoClipX. I don't really like the UI and there are too many option IMHO, but it does provide a fairly good select (copy) & paste (middle-click) functionality. It's not perfect though (I don't think TXMouse was either) and one nice thing is it can play a sound on copy so you know when it didn't copy for some reason.

Like TXMouse, some application (Putty, KVIrc some browsers w/ addons) have the functionality bundled and it can be disabled by adding these apps in a blacklist.

Comment: I was looking into this while working with a loaner laptop... Trying TXMouse again it's working quite well actually, and it does provide feedback on whenever it copying or not, it's a mouse icon rather then sound. I actually prefer it for two reasons: 1. You don't need sound (ex. works without my headphones...) and 2. You know it's not copying before you even finished selecting the test to copy. I do have browser issue this time (Chrome extension doesn't work as advertised) but I can replace link middle-clicks with control-click which is almost the same.